# No application is associated with the specified file for this operation exception in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm try to print with the Class `Process` and I get this exception:

"No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"

This is my code:

```
byte[] fileStresm = getFileStresm();
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileStresm );

try
{
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
      CreateNoWindow = true,
      Verb = "print",
      FileName = filePath //put the correct path here
   };
   p.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to open the file you’re creating?

Comment: Can you doubleclick the file in Windows Explorer to open it?

Comment: So, on your system, in Windows Explorer, if you right-click on a `.pdf` file, is there a `Print` option in the context menu? I suspect not, and that's what the error is telling you. Windows itself doesn't know how to print this file and *no other program has registered itself as supporting that operation either*. It doesn't know what to do.

Comment: @Hursey - Yes' I'm see the file that create

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - Yes, it's open by Chrome, but I can to open it as Adobe Reder

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm not have on right click the `print` option, What can I do????

Comment: @Ayal I believe you might need to install a dedicated PDF reader, such as Adobe Acrobat, FoxIt PDF Reader, etc.

Comment: @John - You Wite me before a few minutes answer, Tanx!! It's work very good now!!

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this property:

> UseShellExecute = true

the code:

```
byte[] fileStresm = getFileStresm();
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileStresm );

try
{
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     Verb = "print",
     FileName = filePath //put the correct path here
     UseShellExecute = true
   };
   p.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Since that property defaults to `true`, adding that line of code should have no effect.

Comment: It's very strange, before it was not and I got the error, and then I added this property and there was no error. Now I've erased the property again and I'm leaving an error again, why is this happening ??

Answer (score 0):

```
UseShellExecute = true
```

This likely fixes the issue if you're working on a .NET Core application. The default value for UseShellExecute is `false` for .NET Core apps and `true` for .NET framework apps.